# Cordova InAppBrowser PDF- iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My code is working but not exactly the way I want.  I'm using the plugin `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`. I have an anchor tag to click and opens up a **pdf**. The code is as follows:

```
$("#lnkTools").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        url = 'someExternalLink.pdf';
        var options = {location: 'yes', clearcache: 'no', toolbar:'no', closebuttoncaption: 'DONE?'};

        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options);

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that, the PDF doesn't open if I don't exit the app, I have to exit the app first and get back in for the PDF to open up.  What am I missing?  When I try to use `_system` same thing, before it opens up the browser, I still need to exit the app first.

EDIT:

When I try to change the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/main');` in my app.js to  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');` it's working, well.  Why is this like this? when I place a `$state.go('app.main')` in my login controller, it loops.  Is there any way I can get through this?

Comment: Are you sure that the click-listener is called on the very first time? If this lnkTools-element was inserted dynamically after defining a click-listener, then this [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function might help you.

Comment: yes i'm very sure, I checked just by putting alert and it fires immediately

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?